# curl mydb/_changes?feed=continuous disconnects after about 20 seconds

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

Based on the API reference, the [continuous](https://docs.cloudant.com/database.html#the-feed-argument) parameter will keep the connection open. However, the following curl command returns after about 20 seconds, which seems not true according to the API reference. Could anyone explain this? Thanks.

```
curl https://cloudant-URL-bluemix.cloudant.com/mydb/_changes?feed=continuous --http1.1
```

Returns:

> "last_seq":"11-g1AAAAYeeJy11M1NwzAUB3DTIiFOdAM4wLElbpzYPtENYAPw84dKlaYItWfYADaADWAD2AA2gA3KBsWuEampSpIiLo4UWb9_3nt2MoRQq99U6ECBHF3qngIcdWDYlrKtRNaO4o7MRhMl8nEn1-PMbm8IBDuz2WzQb4qNoX2xRSQXkkZVERe3_70zLUmDll1h9ysQzQM5JEaBDdye5Eqb81yrEE3K0D2HHgYoIZIow1ej3TI0cuhRiBolKFtCa3Qbek49DlXNmDB69afSMvTEoacBGiexTDX9Q1PPHDoKUYkBuuSX-nGZeuHUq-DAqTQ2WsRVnZodzzftiq7tw4beuNTGPFXTLgCV_3PMfeitD70rQqXAnLGkIlVvYD7z3mc-FEMTmCjtCl33Jnj40cNPDm76YjTXkUgrUmuN7dmHvhTVUA1M8KUjWHc0rx5-W7iF1EQGx-tfGA-_e3hazJwTLhmBitSPNlWbzYcPXfyncqmxYovVDD4Bc-fgbg","pending":0}

Comment: Downvoters: please add a comment when down voting so users can learn where they need to improve their questions,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
curl 'https://cloudant-URL-bluemix.cloudant.com/mydb/_changes?feed=continuous&heatbeat=1000'
```

It's probably timing out if there are no changes to report on. See

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html